# Built native lib in android studio error - ndk-build.cmd finished with non-zero exit value 2 execute problem in Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I`m trying to build [strongswan lib](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/tree/master/src) but in windows machine. I follow all the steps from the [strongswan wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AndroidVPNClientBuild) , but i gain this error when i tried to build the project.

```
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:buildNative'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\kristiyan.varbanov\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:222)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:202)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:342)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.run(BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.java:39)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Users\kristiyan.varbanov\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\kristiyan.varbanov\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build" (in directory "C:\Users\kristiyan.varbanov\Desktop\strongswan\src\frontends\android\app\src\main\jni"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 11 more
```

I saw that problem is that ndk-build can't be found, but i`m sure that ndk and sdk directories are correct,double check them.

Here is my build.gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.strongswan.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 62
        versionName "2.0.2"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] // disables the default ndk-build call (with on-the-fly Android.mk files)
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }

    task buildNative(type: Exec) {
        workingDir 'src/main/jni'
        commandLine "${android.ndkDirectory}/ndk-build", '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    }

    task cleanNative(type: Exec) {
        workingDir 'src/main/jni'
        commandLine "${android.ndkDirectory}/ndk-build", 'clean'
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }

    clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**EDIT:**

i saw that the problem can be

```
        commandLine "${android.ndkDirectory}/ndk-build.cmd", '-C', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
```

ndk-build must be ndk-build.cmd because i use windows machine. But when i change this line i gain this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\kristiyan.varbanov\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: It's time to progress to built-in C++ support in Android Studio 3.2 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the Stacktrace, and I saw that the error was that Gradle want`s to execute program ndk-build in folder:

> C:\Users\kristiyan.varbanov\Desktop\strongswan\src\frontends\android\app\src\main\jni

As you have configured in "task buildNative" in gradle file.

You need to check if ndk-build is in the specified folder, but I presume that you have misconfigured the buildNative task.

Comment: i changed ndk-build with ndk-build.cmd and get new error which is:                 
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\kristiyan.varbanov\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2